# python can not find attribute Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

my python code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
from time import sleep,ctime
loops=[4,2]

def loop(nloop,nsec):
    print 'start loop',nloop,'at:',ctime()
    sleep(nsec)
    print 'loop',nloop,'done at:',ctime()

def main():
    print 'starting at:',ctime()
    threads=[]
    nloops = range(len(loops))

    for i in nloops:
        t = threading.Thread(target = loop, args = (i,loops[i]))
        threads.append(t)
    for i in nloops:
        threads[i].start()
    for i in nloops:
        threads[i].join()
    print 'all Done at:',ctime()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but python output is:

```
t = threading.Thread(target = loop, args = (i,loops[i]))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
Exception AttributeError: '_shutdown' in <module 'threading'
```

i reinstall python ,but this issue still have ,how to fix it?

Comment: Pro tip: Always include the *full* traceback of an error when reporting a python problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I bet you have a local file named `threading.py`, and it's masking the system `threading` module.

You can verify this by printing `threading.__file__`:

```
import threading
print threading.__file__
```

to get the file path of the module that is being imported.

Rename it, or delete it, to fix this.